# Convert a string array to a new row

Tags: vba, excel

I have a string array that i want to insert as a new row at the end of the sheet using xlDown.

Iv'e tried `Range("A1:A" & UBound(strArr) + 1) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(strArr)`

But it copies that to a column and not to the lowest row..

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `Resize` the Range to size of the array (you need to modify the `Column` dimension). Since the array starts at 0, and Column starts at 1 we add 1, so the syntax is: `Range("A" & LastRow + 1).Resize(, UBound(strArr) + 1).Value`.

Second, `LastRow` finds the last row with data (in Column A), so we `+1` to write the result on the next empty row (1 row below).

Try the code below:

```
Dim LastRow As Long

LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row '<-- get last row in Column A

Range("A" & LastRow + 1).Resize(, UBound(strArr) + 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(WorksheetFunction.Transpose(strArr))
```

Comment: תודה רבה שי!, עובד מעולה

Comment: @YuvalSegev חחח , בבקשה

Answer (score 0):

Using this, this will ensure you are getting last row of the sheet as anything that is detected will make that the last row.

```
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

Range("A" & lastrow).Resize(, UBound(strArr)).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(strArr)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim strArr As Variant

    strArr = Array("a", "b", "c")

    Range("A" & last_row + 1 & ":A" & last_row + UBound(strArr) + 1) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(strArr)

End Sub

Public Function last_row(Optional str_sheet As String, Optional column_to_check As Long = 1) As Long

    Dim shSheet  As Worksheet

        If str_sheet = vbNullString Then
            Set shSheet = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
        Else
            Set shSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(str_sheet)
        End If

    last_row = shSheet.Cells(shSheet.Rows.Count, column_to_check).End(xlUp).Row

End Function
```

The trick is that you should find the last row and then use the size of the array to calculate the size of the new range.
Like this:

```
Range("A" & last_row + 1 & ":A" & last_row + UBound(strArr) + 1) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(strArr)
```